# LINGUAGEM R: Erro "Error in curso[[1:98]] : indexação recursiva falhou no nível 2" ao tentar pesquisar os itens de uma lista, como resolvo?

Tags: r, lista

Tenho uma lista "curso" no R, ela é composta por 98 itens, cada item possui uma ou duas variáveis do tipo character. Quero todas as primeiras variáveis de cada iten da lista, mas ao digitar o comando:

> curso[[1:98]][1]

Recebo o seguinte erro no console:
Error in curso[[1:98]] : indexação recursiva falhou no nível 2

Não faço ideia do que seja, a sintaxe que eu usei parece ser a certa, nem é nada complexo. Tô muito frustrado com isso, podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[[ ]]` só retorna valores individuais, normalmente se usando um inteiro ou uma string com ele.

Se você passar um vetor ele procura recursivamente. `X[[1:2]]` é o mesmo que `X[[1]][[2]]`. Por isso ele deu seu erro de recursão.

No R você pode fazer a sua operação com um `for` ou uma função do tipo `apply`:

```r
teste <- list(
  a1 = list("a", "b"),
  a2 = list("a", "c"),
  a3 = list("a", "d"),
  a4 = list("a", "e")
)


novo_teste <- list()
for(i in 1:length(teste)){
  novo_teste[[i]] <- teste[[i]][[2]]
}
novo_teste
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "d"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "e"

lapply(teste, function(x) x[[2]])
#> $a1
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> $a2
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> $a3
#> [1] "d"
#> 
#> $a4
#> [1] "e"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: O operador `[` age como uma função, pode passá-lo diretamente para **apply*: `lapply(teste, "[[", 2)`

Answer (score 4):

Da para usar a funcao map do tidyverse de algumas formas

```r
library(tidyverse)

teste <- list(
  a1 = list("a", "b"),
  a2 = list("a", "c"),
  a3 = list("a", "d"),
  a4 = list("a", "e")
)

teste %>%
  map(~ .x[[2]])
#> $a1
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> $a2
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> $a3
#> [1] "d"
#> 
#> $a4
#> [1] "e"


teste %>%
  map(2)
#> $a1
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> $a2
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> $a3
#> [1] "d"
#> 
#> $a4
#> [1] "e"

teste %>%
  map(~ pluck(.x, 2))
#> $a1
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> $a2
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> $a3
#> [1] "d"
#> 
#> $a4
#> [1] "e"

# se vc pricisar de characters use map_chr

teste %>%
  map_chr(2)
#>  a1  a2  a3  a4 
#> "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>